# How to get Entity Framework's singularized and pluralized table names in a DB-first approach?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.0. with a database-first approach.

I enabled "Singularized or Pluralized" option when creating the `DbContext`. I know the table names from database, now I want to get the singularized or pluralized table names programatically.

Example:

- Employees - Employee,
- Roles - Role,
- Courses - Cours

Is there any way to get the singularized or pluralized entity names programatically?

Comment: "get the singularized or pluralized table names programatically" What to you mean exactly ? when will it be plural ? when will it be singular ? Or you want to allow both ?

Comment: if you want to stop pluralize names then you can add following in onmodelcreating        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

Comment: I want to get both entity framework pluralize or singularize names for table.  Some Cases I need singularize Table name , some other case pluralize  table Name. Ex: TableName in DB as "Employees" . When I Enabled singularize Entity Name is "Employee".

Comment: HI Pavvy, I can't  stop Pluralize options. I have requirement to get in  both cases.